# Can I Change Box background color on click in material ui with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-design

I want to change the background color of my Box whenever it is clicked.
OOTB i couldn't find something which could help my use case.
SO, I tried using events onClick but couldn't find the right event which could bring info on selected event and allow me to change the styling value.

Use Case -

> i am creating multiple box dynamically and at once only one Box could be highlighted

```
 {allSports !== null &&
        allSports?.map((sports) => (
          <Grid
            item
            xs={4}
            sx={{ mx: "auto", my: 1, minWidth: "80%" }}
            onClick={backgroundChange}
          >
            <Item
            //   onClick={() => sportChoose(sports)}
            >
              <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
                <Box>
                  <img
                    src={
                      require(`../../../../../resources/images/sportsIcons/${sports.icon}`)
                        .default
                    }
                  />
                </Box>
                <Box sx={{ m: "auto" }}>
                  <Typography variant="h6">{sports.name}</Typography>
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </Item>
          </Grid>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { FC, ReactElement, useState } from 'react'
import { Box } from '@mui/material'

export const MuiCard: FC = (): ReactElement => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
  const toggleClicked = () => setClicked((prev) => !prev)
  return (
    <Box
      component="div"
      onClick={toggleClicked}
      sx={{ height: 20, backgroundColor: clicked ? 'red' : 'white' }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam, Sorry i think i didn't elaborated my use case in question, i am creating multiple box dynamically and at one time only one could be highlighted , so once i will started selecting boxes it will highlight every clicked one.

Comment: Can you add an example or an image of what you're trying to achieve/build?